# How do I encrypt a new SD card?

Tags: 7.0-nougat, disk-encryption

I'm on Android Nougat with an encrypted phone. I added a new SD card but cannot find an option to encrypt it too.

How do I go about encrypting the new SD card?

Comment: Did you check settings>security>encrypt sd?

Comment: @Abochur I checked and there is no option to encrypt the card.

Comment: It might be a bit too late, but for clarity, could you mention the device model?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this helps, but I'm also on Nougat (Gal. S8).  I found in Settings>Lock Screen and Security>Encrypt SD Card. Good Luck...

Answer (score 0):

On my Moto G4 running Android 7.0:

- Settings -> Storage; select the SD card (OK to mount the SD card if prompted to do that).  This shows the contents of the SD card.
- From the drop-down menu in the top-right corner (3 vertical dots):  choose "Storage Settings".
- Choose "Format as internal"